# How to set BitArray to set specfic Bits based on value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, bit-manipulation, bitarray

How do I use BitArray to do a few things such the most basic, setting a value to bits, not just bits! I am starting to regret ever using this crap called BitArray.

Say I got bits such as this.

```
public enum RULE
{
    NOTHING = 0x0,
    FIRST_STEP = 0x1,
    FOO_YOU = 0x2,
    BAR_FOO = 0x10,
    FOO = 0x20,
    BAR = 0x40,
    FOO_BAR = 0x80,
    READY = 0x100,
    ...//LOTS MORE BITS
    FINAL_FLAG_BIT= 0x10000000 //Final bit.. uses the 29th bit.
};
```

Now say I do this..

```
//only use 29 bits to save memory, probably still uses 4 bytes lol.
BitArray rules= new BitArray(29);

//As you can see what I tried to do.
public bool ruleEnabled(RULE i)
{
    return rules[(int)i]; //<- this is impossible as it sets BITS not bitmasks.
}

public void setRule(RULE rule, bool b) {
    rules.Set((int)rule, b);
}
```

So I wasted around 30 minutes implementing this without knowing one of it's many limitations.. You know there isn't even any way to cast it down to it's value.. without using `CopyTo`

So I ended up using just 1 variable (seems this solution is both cleaner and faster) and only had to alter 2 methods `setRule` and `ruleEnabled` for it to work properly.

```
private int rules; //uses only 29 of the 32 bits.
public bool ruleEnabled(RULE i)
{
    int bits = (int)i;
    return (rules & bits) == bits;
}

public void setRule(RULE rule, bool set) {
    if (set)
        rules |= (int)rule;
    else
        rules &= ~(int)rule;
}
```

My question is did I do the right thing? and why is the BitArray ever useful for? if it has so much limitations.. you can do all of it's operations such as `AND` `OR` `NOT` `XOR` already with `&` `|` `~` `^`

I guess BitArray is best used when you are dealing with more bits then any datatype can represent.. for compressions/encryptions etc..

Comment: Seems like you have a pretty good understand now.

Comment: Meh yeah I completely removed BitArray after I posted this question.. but I hope this can help others who are googling this question and are struggling with BitArray to hopefully switch over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitArray is accessed by index, not by flags.  For instance, for a bit array with length 29, the only possible indexes range from 0 through 28.  Thus, the following is invalid:

```
rules[RULE.READY] = true; // where READY is equal to 0x100, but the
                    // bit array's length is only 29.
```

To make it work as intended, you must convert the flag to an index first.  The following function may help:

```
public static int FlagToIndex(int flag){
   int i=0;
   if(flag==0)return i;
   while((flag&1)==0){
     flag>>=1;
     i++;
   }
   return i;
}
```

With this function you can now properly index the bit array:

```
rules[FlagToIndex((int)RULE.READY)] = true;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps sure but way to much things going on there even a loop haha.